# Export To Csv from Custom Admin Grid

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have a custom admin grid and trying to add the Export to CSV option. I've added it already and the button works as well. The problem occurs when I try to export it, it only exports visible records. I dont have the MassActions setup so I can't really SELECT ALL and stuff.

How can I make it so whenever I hit the export to csv button, it exports ALL records instead of the visible ones.

Answer (score 4):

In your custom grid class you need to call method `addExportType` from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` class
Code of protected function `_prepareColumns()` in your Grid class:
Add the below code under `_prepareColumns`.

```
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv',
         Mage::helper('your_helper')->__('CSV'));
return parent::_prepareColumns();
```

This will generate the Export button and once that done go to controllers file and the action to call the CSV

```
public function exportCsvAction()
{
    $fileName   = 'yourfilename.csv';
    $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('modulename/adminhtml_modelname_grid')
    ->getCsvFile();
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
}
protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream')
{
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType);
}
```

and once that done CSV will be generate. `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` class have other methods also for generating Excel files.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thats not the issue. The issue is in my `_prepareCollection()` function.

What is happening is that I have the below code snippet after my $collection statements

`$this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();`

After the above code, I have a foreach running in `_prepareCollection()` which causes the Csv export to only export visible fields

Comment: Can you add your full collection code please.

Comment: Please read the question. He's asking for non standard behaviour.

Comment: @RobbieAverill you should read it again. What is non standard behavior refer here can you explain ?

Comment: The problem is likely the foreach, which loads the collection and is limiting the results.  If OP can post the full code, we could recommend suggestions to rewrite the code without the foreach.

Answer (score 4):

In your _prepareColumns function in grid class, just need put these code in:

```
if($this->_isExport) {
  $this->addColumn('col_name', array(
     'header' => 'col_name',
     'index'  => 'col_name'
  ));
}
```

In this code block, col_name is not visible field on grid which you want to export.

Comment: This is the correct answer, should be upvoted and marked as the accepted answer.